# passing two parameters to fminunc function

Tags: matlab, optimization

I use MATLAB optimization toolbox function `fminunc` to optimize two parameters with different lengths based on my objective function. I need to optimize both parameters. The algorithm needs to start with an initial points for these parameters:

```
x0 = randn(10,3);
y0 = rand(20,1);

options = optimoptions(@fminunc,'Algorithm','quasi-newton');
[Coeff_min, Error_min] = fminunc(@objectiveFunction, x0, options)
```

How can I pass both initial parameters to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is fool matlab to think you only have one parameter of `numel` 10*3 + 20:

```
function v = objective_wrapper( xy )
x = reshape(xy(1:30),10,3);
y = reshape(xy(31:end),20,1);
v = objectiveFunction(x,y);
```

Now you can optimize:

```
xy0 = [x0(:);y0(:)];
[Coeff_min, Error_min] = fminunc(@objective_wrapper, xy0, options);
```

Comment: 36  secs faster and correct size of `x` :) congrats

Comment: Thank you so much, Code works well. Is it possible to pass the parameters instead of challenging with indexes?